# Technical Report Number Field in Mendeley-Exported bibtex file

Tags: bibtex, mendeley

the problems with Mendeley and their bibtex exportation are numerous, but I am currently facing the following issue:

#### The Issue

For dissertations, my university requires to include the technical report number in citations. For the life of me, I can't get Mendeley to include this information in the bibtex file and now I have to include that info by hand for 20+ entries. I'm looking for a better way.

#### What I've tried so far:

- In Mendeley, select document type *Report*
- Include *Number* field within Mendeley (Preferences-> Document Details->Document Type = Report-> select *Number*)
- Fill the field information by hand
- Click *Sync* to create the new .bib file

#### Result:

Field number (number = {...}) does not appear in the generated .bib file

#### Current Workaround:

- Generate the .bib fiel with Mendeley
- Copy the generated .bib file
- Open the copy with a text editor
- Search for entry by hand
- Add number = {...} by hand
- Repeat

#### Looking for:

An automation for this, or an option in Mendeley to include Report Number information. Hacks welcome. Anything but to do it by hand!

Thanks!

Comment: Your write-up is not at all easy to follow. For instance, why are you not trying to create an entry of type `@techreport`? `@techreport` is a standard BibTeX entry type, whereas `@report` is not.

Comment: *Report* is a Mendeley entry type which gets exported as *@techreport* in the BibTeX file generated automatically by Mendeley. As a user, I have no influence in naming or creating document types in Mendeley.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by accident. The field *Issue* below field *year* gets exported as *number = {...}* in the bibtex file.